# C++ tron AI stuck in its own trail

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am having a bit of trouble putting together an AI for my tron game. The AI should be moving in a way to avoid the map's borders and its own trail. The issue is that a trail is suppose to appear right behind the AI each time it moves so this causes the AI not to move at all since its setting off the if statement "if trail, dont move" so i am a little confused on what I should do in this situation.

```
void AIBike(){
        srand(time(0)); // use time to seed random number
        int AI; // random number will be stored in this variable
        AI = rand()%4 + 1; // Selects a random number 1 - 4.
        Map[AIy][AIx]= trail; // trail is char = '*'

        if (AI == 1){
            if(Map[AIy][AIx]!='x' && Map[AIy][AIx]!=trail){
                AIx = AIx - 1;
            }
        }


       else if (AI == 2){
            if(Map[AIy][AIx]!='x' && Map[AIy][AIx]!=trail){
                AIx = AIx + 1;
            }
        }

        else if(AI == 3){
            if(Map[AIy][AIx]!='x' && Map[AIy][AIx]!=trail){
            AIy = AIy + 1;

            }
        }

        else if(AI == 4){
            if(Map[AIy][AIx]!='x' && Map[AIy][AIx]!=trail){
            AIy = AIy - 1;

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You may not want to call `srand(time(0))` in your function. You should call that in your `main`. If `AIBike` gets called repeatedly, you risk seeding the random number generator with the same time value over and over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I'd write it:

```
// I prefer arrays of constants instead of the copy-paste technology
const int dx[] = { 1, 0, -1, 0 };
const int dy[] = { 0, 1, 0, -1 };

int newAIx = AIx + dx[AI - 1];
int newAIy = AIy + dy[AI - 1];

if (/* newAIx and newAIy are inside the field and */ Map[newAIy][newAIx] != 'x' && Map[newAIy][newAIx] != trail) {
  Map[AIy][AIx] = trail;
  AIx = newAIx;
  AIy = newAIy;
}
```

I removed a large amount of similar code and moved trail creation after checking for it, but before actually making a move.

Comment: Excellent idea! but one problem, the AI seems to ignore the border completely but does try to avoid its own trail, why is that? the border would be Map[AIy][AIx] != 'x'

Comment: never mind, i noticed the newAI wasn't applied to the border as well.

Answer (score 1):

`Map[AIy][AIx]= trail;`and`Map[AIy][AIx]!=trail`seem to conflict...
What you need to do to detect the collision is to say [for example]:

```
    else if(AI == 3){
        if(Map[AIy][AIx]!='x' && Map[AIy+1][AIx]!=trail){
        AIy = AIy + 1;

        }
    }
```

Notice that I detect if the *next* position would be a collision, rather than detect if you're on top of it.